# How to separate the repeater data by number of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

For example, we have 19 items on the repeater datasource. And we wanted to separate them using 
 by 5 items.

It's like

```
01 02 03 04 05 <br />
06 07 08 09 10 <br />
11 12 13 14 15 <br />
16 17 18 19
```

How are we going to do this in asp.net repeater? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a seperator template like so

```
<SeperatorTemplate><br /></SeperatorTemplate>
```

Then you have to bind ItemDataBound event before you call DataBind() on the repeater.
In this event you look at the item count and display seperator when you can divide the item count by 5, like so:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Seperator)
  e.Item.Visible = ((e.Item.Parent as Repeater).Items.Count % 5 == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have also tried <%#CreateSeparator(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex", ""))%> call to a function on the code-behind and it also works. But which is faster?

Comment: Thanks, this is the perfect solution save for a different spelling in my Visual Studio!!!

`<SeparatorTemplate> I can't spell either </SeparatorTemplate>`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the ListView. It implements a property called GroupCount.